# How to raise an error manually without showing its cause

Tags: python, exception

I got an error saying:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    hello(abcd)
  File "C:\Users\intel\RaiseError.py", line 7, in hello
    raise SyntaxError("Invalid Syntax")
SyntaxError: Invalid Syntax
```

I don't want it to show the cause, that is:

```
File "C:\Users\intel\RaiseError.py", line 7, in hello
    raise SyntaxError("Invalid Syntax")
```

I just want it to give back an error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    hello(abcd)
SyntaxError: Invalid Syntax
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to suppress or customize the traceback and only show a simplified error message, you can achieve this by catching the exception and then printing a custom error message. Here's an example of how you can do that:

```py
def hello(arg):
    try:
        # Your code here
        pass
    except SyntaxError as e:
        print(f"SyntaxError: {e}")

# Example usage:
abcd = "some invalid code"
hello(abcd)
```

In this code, we've enclosed the code that might raise a `SyntaxError` in a `try` block. If a `SyntaxError` occurs, it will be caught in the `except` block, and we can print a custom error message using `print(f"SyntaxError: {e}")`. This way, you can display a simplified error message without the traceback information.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend that you leverage the traceback module to customize how the exception is shown to the user.

Module documentation:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html

Short example:

```
import traceback

try:
    assert 1 == 2
except Exception as exc:
    traceback.print_exc(limit=0)
```